# issue with retrieving view model value in a computed function

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following knockout viewmodel although I'm not able to get the value selected from a select dropdown, shown below.  I can't see why but I can get it working using jquery but not from the actual ko model?!  Can anyone see why this is a problem for me?

http://jsfiddle.net/35SuT/6/

Many many thanks!
Razor

**Knockout setup**

```
(function(ns) {
    var jsonObject = {
        "People": [
          {"Selected":false, "Text":"Tom", "Value":"1"},
          {"Selected":false, "Text":"Jane", "Value":"2"},
          {"Selected":false, "Text":"Sarah", "Value":"2"},
          {"Selected":false, "Text":"Olive", "Value":"3"},
          {"Selected":false, "Text":"Other", "Value":"4"}]};

          var viewModel = new ViewModel(jsonObject);            
          ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

})(namespace("so.question"));
```

**View model**

```
var ViewModel = (function (dump) {
    var panels = {
    Area1: {
        peopleArray: ko.observableArray(dump.People),
        peopleSelected: ko.observable(self.peopleSelected) 
    }};

    return panels;
});
```

**THIS WORKS**

```
panels.Area.get = ko.computed(function () {
    return $('#people option:selected').text())  // THIS WORKS
}, this);
```

**THIS FAILS**

```
panels.Section1.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return panels.Section1.)  // BUT THIS FAILS!??
}, this);
```

**Markup**

```
<!--This markup does show the array correctly-->
<select id="people" data-bind="options: panels.peopleArray, optionsText: 'Text'"></select>
```

Comment: you viewmodel is quite fishy. can you make it simple

Comment: I can refactor it but not right now..  Can you say exactly why it only works with jquery?  (I assume you refer to 'fishy' as because I'm not using functions?)

Comment: here is a fiddle. Please modify so that it can work. http://jsfiddle.net/35SuT/3/. Then we can do live implementation

Comment: Regarding the "fishy" part - from what you have written the "panels.peopleArray" referenced in bindings should be undefined (it is inside 'panels.Area1', the 'peopleSelected' array is never used (and its definition refer to another array 'self.peopleSelected' which is never defined), and your code in the "this fails" section is not valid javascript. Most of it is probably due to missing parts, but it makes difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've been trying to get it working but failing, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/35SuT/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is You don't have to add select event to the control. Efficient way is to subscribe on selection changes

You can Do it Like this way, Using **Subscribe**

```
  viewModel.panels.Area1.peopleSelected.subscribe(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            panels.Area1.peopleSelected(data);
            //Set selection value to your observable variable
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't bind correctly. BTW, I am confused that your question and your jsfidder are using different code!

Fix the binding in your question:

```
<select id="people" data-bind="value: panels.peopleSelected,
  options: panels.peopleArray, optionsText: 'Text'"></select>
```

Fix the binding in your jsfidder: (no () on selectedTitle, you want to bind the observable, not its value)

```
<select data-bind="options: Section1.titlesArray; optionsText: 'Text',
  value: Section1.selectedTitle, optionsValue: 'Value'"></select>
```